# How to define a discord message as a string or variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, brain.js

I'm making a Discord bot that can put peoples' messages into different types of categories to respond to. For some reason it keeps suggesting that the `Discord.Message.content` is `undefined` when I try to run it.

I've tried searching up if I was defining it correctly and couldn't find much. I'm doing this with Brain.js:

```js
const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM(); 

const trainingData = data.map(item => ({
    input: item.message,
    output: item.category
}));

network.train(trainingData, {
    interations: 2000
});

bot.on('message', msg =>{
    const raw = network.run(Discord.Message.content)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    const raw = network.run(Discord.Message.content)
})
```

with this:

```
bot.on('message', msg =>{
    const raw = network.run(msg.content)
})
```

`Discord.Message` is the type of object (aka "class"), whereas `msg` is the object itself. The docs will refer to `Message` objects, which `msg` is one of, but to access the content of a specific message you need to use the variable holding that specific message, which is `msg`.

Comment: ```const raw = network.run(message.content)
                        ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\John\Desktop\Electrolyte Bot\index.js:30:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11```

Comment: @JonathanSmith you need to use the version of message you use in your bot.on ready

Comment: @JonathanSmith Remember, in programming, the exact phrasing matters. You're using `msg`, not `message`, as your argument to the function that you run when the bot gets a message, so you need to get the content from `msg` instead of from `message`. Therefore, you should use `const raw = network.run(msg.content)`. I assume you're new to programming; I'd recommend checking out a free Javascript tutorial to help you with some of these basic elements, it'll go a long way to helping you understand the language better. Good luck!